# Why do not all started applications save the wanted information in the text files as expected?

Tags: batch-file, save

I am trying to create a batch file on a USB drive that will run an .exe, save its text to a .txt file, and then close the .exe.

I am currently running into a weird problem, only 5 of the 18 .exe's are actually saving their text to a file.

This is the convention I am using to complete my task:

```
start IEPassView.exe /stext Results/IEPassView.txt 
taskkill /f /im IEPassView.exe

start MailPassView.exe /stext Results/MailPassView.txt
taskkill /f /im MailPassView.exe

start MessenPass.exe /stext Results/MessenPass.txt
taskkill /f /im MessenPass.exe

start RouterPassView.exe /stext Results/RouterPassView.txt
taskkill /f /im RouterPassView.exe

start ProtectedStoragePassView.exe /stext Results/ProtectedStoragePassView.txt
taskkill /f /im ProtectedStoragePassView.exe

start DialUpPassView.exe /stext Results/DialUpPassView.txt
taskkill /f /im DialUpPassView.exe
```

I have 18 of the above blocks in a row all calling different small programs and even though 5 of them actually save the files none of them save a .cfg file as they sometimes do. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You are really wondering why some applications fail to create the text file before the started application is __killed__ (not terminated) by the operating system? What about giving the applications the chance to do their job before __killing__ them? Is it really necessary to __kill__ the applications at all because otherwise they would run forever? Are the applications GUI or console applications? Comment all `taskkill` lines and remove all `start` commands and test if that is better.

Comment: @Mofi the killing of all the tasks became a necessity.  At first I did not include that command at all but it would open and run all the programs and then leave all 18 of them open until I manually closed them.  I will try your suggestion but may I ask why I would remove the start command?  Is it just redundant and the programs will start by default with the command?

Answer (score 1):

There are **mainly** 3 different types of executables:

- A **console application** is reading from **stdin** or a file and writing to **stdout** or a file and outputs error messages to **stderr**.

  The processing of a batch file is halted on **starting** a console application until the console application terminated itself. The correct term is therefore: **calling** a console application.

  The exit code of the console application is assigned to environment variable **ERRORLEVEL** and can be also directly evaluated for example with `if errorlevel X rem do something`

  Many *.exe in `System32` directory of Windows are such console applications, like `find.exe`, `findstr.exe`, `ping.exe`, ...
- A **GUI** (graphical user interface) application is **started** as new process which means the Windows command processor does not halt batch processing until the GUI application terminates itself.

  It is not easily possible to get something from within a command process from such applications. GUI applications are designed for interacting via a graphical user interface with a user and not via standard streams or files with a command process.

  A typical example for such applications is *Windows Explorer* `explorer.exe` in Windows directory.
- A **hybrid** application supports both interfaces and can be therefore used from within a command process as well as by a user via GUI.

  Hybrid applications are rare because not easy to code. The behavior of hybrid applications on usage from within a batch file must be find out by testing.

  Example for such applications are *Windows Registry Editor* `regedit.exe` or shareware archiver tool *WinRAR* `WinRAR.exe`.

It is best to look on simple examples to see the differences regarding starting/calling all 3 types of applications from within a batch file.

**Example for console application:**

```
@echo off
cls
%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe 127.0.0.1 -n 5
echo.
echo Ping finished pinging the own computer (localhost).
echo.
pause
```

The command processing is halted until `ping.exe` terminated itself which takes 4 seconds. There is no need for `start` or `call` for such applications, except the console application should be intentionally executed in a separate process.

**Example for a GUI application:**

```
@echo off
cls
%WinDir%\Explorer.exe
echo.
echo Windows Explorer opened and is still running!
echo.
pause
```

This batch file outputs the text and message prompt to press any key immediately after starting Windows Explorer indicating that Windows Explorer was started as separate process and Windows command processor immediately continued on the next lines of the batch file. So although Windows Explorer was started and is still running, the batch processing continued, too.

**Example for a hybrid application:**

```
@echo off
cls
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe"
echo.
echo User exited WinRAR.
echo.
pause
```

This batch file starts *WinRAR* without any parameter (usually not useful from within a batch file) if being installed at all in default installation directory. But batch processing is halted until the user exited *WinRAR* for example by clicking on **X** symbol of the *WinRAR*´s application window.

But opening a command prompt window and executing from within the window

```
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe"
```

results in getting immediately the prompt back in command window to type and execute the next command. So *WinRAR* finds out what is the parent process and acts accordingly.

*Windows Registry Editor* shows the same behavior. Executing from within a command prompt window

```
%WinDir%\regedit.exe
```

results in opening *Windows Registry Editor*, but next command can be immediately entered in command prompt window. But using this command in a batch file results in halting batch processing until GUI window of *Windows Registry Editor* is closed by the user.

Therefore hybrid applications are used from within a batch file mainly with parameters to avoid the necessity of user interaction.

---

Okay, back to the question after this brief lesson about various types of applications.

First suggestion is using

```
Result\TextFileName.txt
```

instead of

```
Result/TextFileName.txt
```

as the directory separator on Windows is the backslash character, except the executables require forward slashes as directory separator because of being badly ported from Unix/Linux to Windows.

Second suggestion is finding out type of application. Is command `start` really necessary because the applications don't start itself in a separate process and need user interaction to terminate itself?

Note: Command `start` interprets first double quoted string as `title` string. Therefore it is always good to specify as first parameter `""` (empty title string) on starting a GUI or hybrid application as a separate process. On starting a console application as a separate process it is in general a good idea to give the console window a meaningful title.

And last if the started applications really would need user interaction to terminate, it would be definitely better to either start and kill them after waiting 1 or more seconds between start and kill or start them all, wait a few seconds and finally kill them all at once.

Example for first solution with starting and killing each application separately:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set TimeoutInSeconds=3
call :RunApp IEPassView
call :RunApp MailPassView
call :RunApp MessenPass
call :RunApp RouterPassView
call :RunApp ProtectedStoragePassView
call :RunApp DialUpPassView
endlocal
goto :EOF

:RunApp
start "" "%~1.exe" /stext "Results\%~1.txt"
set /A RetryNumber=TimeoutInSeconds + 1
%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe 127.0.0.1 -n %RetryNumber% >nul
%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /f /im "%~1.exe"
goto :EOF
```

It is also possible to use `timeout` instead of `ping` for the delay if the batch file is only for Windows Vista and later Windows versions.

Example for second solution with starting all applications, wait some seconds and kill them finally all:

```
@echo off
call :StartApp IEPassView
call :StartApp MailPassView
call :StartApp MessenPass
call :StartApp RouterPassView
call :StartApp ProtectedStoragePassView
call :StartApp DialUpPassView

%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe 127.0.0.1 -n 6 >nul

call :KillApp IEPassView
call :KillApp MailPassView
call :KillApp MessenPass
call :KillApp RouterPassView
call :KillApp ProtectedStoragePassView
call :KillApp DialUpPassView

goto :EOF

:StartApp
start "" "%~1.exe" /stext "Results\%~1.txt"
goto :EOF

:KillApp
%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /f /im "%~1.exe"
goto :EOF
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `goto /?`
- `ping /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `start /?`
- `taskkill /?`

See also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

PS: The last two batch code blocks were not tested by me because of not having available the applications.

Comment: Different applications, different ways of communicating to the system correct?

Comment: @Jouster500 That is correct. It always depends on what an application is designed for: interacting with a user, or process automated data via defined interfaces without a user, or in rare cases support both.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest killing all tasks at once, at the end of the very end, possibly after a timeout command with a amount of time appropriate to your system's speed. That may help the issue.

Comment: I will try this suggestion as soon as I get home.  I didn't consider the possibility that it was running the script too fast for my system.  Should I include a timeout between every start and stext command?  I think this may be the case because some of the programs require administrator permission to execute and I have noticed that when the administration prompt displays the batch script does not stop, this may be causing a problem with the iteration altogether.  The plan is to convert the batch to an exe once the batch is complete so I only have to grant admin privilege once at the beginning.

Comment: Sorry for the late responce, in case you had not already played with it till it worked, I would say that unless the propts cancel eachother out a timeout at the end, followed by a kill command should be good enough. Either way, make sure the timeout gives you the time needed to give permissions, seeing as the prompt would not pause the batch.

Hope I could help!