# Command prompt do not close after running batch file which have 'exit' in last line

Tags: java, batch-file, ant, cmd

I am running a batch (*ScanProject.bat*) file using java by following code

```
Process p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start /wait ScanProject.bat "+ BaseProjDir+"\\"+jo.getString("Name")+" "+st.nextToken()); 

System.out.println("Exit value : "+p.waitFor());
```

And following is the batch file code :-

```
%2:
cd %1
ant -f ..\antbuild.xml analyse
exit
```

Batch file run successfully but problem is command prompt window do not closes automatically and hence Process do not terminated automatically and my program wait for infinite time to complete this process.Please suggest me any technique so that cmd **exit** after running **ant -f ..\antbuild.xml analyse** command.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cd /D "Full path of directory"` or `pushd "Full path of directory"` with `popd` before exit is better to switch the current directory to any directory on any drive (**cd** and **pushd**/**popd**) or even to a network share (just **pushd**/**popd**). Run in a command prompt window `cd /?` and `pushd /?` for details.

`cmd /C` starts a new Windows command process with closing the process automatically after last command was executed. Run in a command prompt window `cmd /?` for details on options of Windows command interpreter.

**start** is a command to start a new Windows command process or a GUI/hybrid application in a separate process.

So what you do here is starting a new Windows command process which starts a new Windows command process.

Running in a command prompt window `start /?` outputs the help for this command. **start** interprets often the first double quoted string as title string for the new command process. This causes often troubles on command lines with at least 1 double quoted string. Therefore usage of **start** requires often an explicit definition of a title string in double quotes as first argument for **start** which can be even an empty string, i.e. simply `""` as first argument after **start**.

As it can be read after running `exit /?` in a command prompt window, this command without `/B` always exits the current Windows command process immediately. So when `ant.exe` finished, the command process in which the batch file was processed is definitely terminated.

I'm having no experience on Java development, but in my point of view it should be enough to use the following execution command which does not need a batch file at all.

The Java code line

```
Process p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C cd /D \"" + jo.getString("Name") + "\" && ant.exe -f ..\\antbuild.xml analyse");
```

should be enough to

1. start a new Windows command process,
2. set the current directory within this command process to the drive and directory specified by `jo.getString("Name")` which of course must return a directory path with drive letter and using backslashes as directory separators, and on success
3. execute `ant` in this directory with the specified parameters
4. with terminating the Windows command process automatically after console application `ant.exe` finished if `ant.exe` is a console application.

I'm not sure if `cmd.exe /C` is needed at all.

I suggest to test this command first manually from within a command prompt window. Then use it in the Java application if really working and producing the expected result. And finally I would further test if `cmd.exe /C` is needed at all in Java code.

See [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for details about the operator `&&` to run a command after previous command was successful. And see also [Why do not all started applications save the wanted information in the text files as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37010695/3074564) for an explanation of *console* / *GUI* / *hybrid application*.

**NOTE:** There is also Java `Runtime` method [exec(String[] cmdarray, String[] envp, File dir)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File)) to execute a command like `ant.exe` with its parameters `-f` and `..\antbuild.xml` and `analyse` in the directory defined with third parameter which might be better for this task.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i used exit in callback and it worked, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Swap out exit for taskkill, assuming you do not have any other cmd processes running. Not very graceful but it will get the job done.

```
%2:
cd %1
ant -f ..\antbuild.xml analyse
taskkill /im cmd.exe
```