# Closing CMD automatically closes another program

Tags: cmd

I've been playing around with EnvVar Paths so I can easily start programs from the cmd prompt.

Shortcuts from programs I wish to open using the cmd are copied into a folder X and linked in System Env Paths, and I'm able to execute them using:

```
> start <shortcut>
```

However, I'm facing a strange problem when I try this with **mySQL Workbench** (shortcut is called 'sql.lnk'). After opening the program using

```
> start sql
```

anytime I close the cmd prompt, the mySQL Workbench window *automatically closes* as well.

Does anyone know why this is? I've tried with multiple programs (word, excel, chrome), and none of them give me this behavior.

Comment: In the command prompt window where `start sql` was typed and executed, does prompt blink after executing the command and therefore you can type another command like `dir`? If the answer is no, `sql.exe` is a hybrid application which halts command process until terminated. In this case terminating the command process on clicking on __X__ terminates sql.exe as not being started in a separate process.

Comment: See the answer on [Why do not all started applications save the wanted information in the text files as expected?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37010695/3074564) for an explanation of the different types of applications: console, GUI or hybrid. And see also answer on [Where is “START” searching for executables?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27386403/3074564) as I suppose `start sql` does not result in `start sql.lnk` but in `start sql.exe`.